# Is there an alternative way to express whole line $0 in awk?

Tags: awk, groovy, sed

I have a tab-delimited file `old.txt` whereby I am adding a column header and value.

```
$ cat old.txt
Sepal length    Sepal width Petal length    Petal width Species
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 I. setosa
4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 I. setosa
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 I. setosa
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 I. setosa
5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 I. setosa
```

I would like to add a column with header and contents with awk. I've been using the following command:

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, "name")}  NR>1 {printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, "ABC") }'  old.txt > new.txt
```

which should output the following:

```
Sepal length    Sepal width Petal length    Petal width Species name
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 I. setosa   ABC
4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 I. setosa   ABC
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 I. setosa   ABC
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 I. setosa   ABC
5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 I. setosa   ABC
```

My current problem is that I am trying to emped this command in a Groovy string for an application. However, apparently `$0` is an illegal term within a string in Groovy:

```
illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}"
```

This is the groovy code which is causing the problem:

```
"""
awk 'NR==1 {printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, "name")}  NR>1 {printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, "ABC") }'  old.txt > new.txt
"""
```

So, I am asking:

(1) Is there another way to represent `$0` in awk?

(2) Perhaps there's another command to do this entirely?

Comment: Your question doesn't show us the Groovy code that's causing the error. Can you add that? See [mcve].

Comment: @KeithThompson Very good point, I've edited

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Perhaps `sed '1s/$/\tname/;1!s//\tABC/' file`

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `awk`

There isn't another way to directly refer to `$0` in `awk`.  You can, however, use `$zero`, where `zero` is a variable explicitly set to zero that will, therefore, provide an indirect reference — `$zero` refers to `$0`.  It's a little 'edgy', though.

```
awk 'NR == 1 {zero=0; printf("%s\t%s\n", $zero, "name")}
     NR  > 1 {printf("%s\t%s\n", $zero, "ABC") }'  old.txt
```

At least on macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, the explicit `zero=0;` is needed (either there or in a `BEGIN` section) — otherwise, the complaint is:

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "zero"
```

Presumably, it is interpreting it as an empty string instead of as a zero; the context isn't sufficiently 'numeric' to get it interpreted as zero.

#### Using `sed`

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -e '1s/$/      name/' \
    -e '2,$s/$/    ABC/' old.txt
```

where the long sequences of blanks within the `s///` commands would each be replaced by a tab in some suitable way.  You can write it all on one line if brevity is more important than clarity; you could use a single `-e` option likewise (and then the `-e` is no longer crucial either).

#### Interaction with Groovy

Both these avoid `$` followed by digits — will Groovy complain about `$zero`, `$s` or `$/`?

Comment: I don't think `$zero` would help here. Groovy double-quoted string literals do interpolation. `"$zero"` gives a run-time error: "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: zero".

Comment: Alternative with `awk` is simple string concatenation, `awk 'NR == 1 && $0 = $0 " name"'`

Comment: @KeithThompson: so the problem is how many programs are getting a chance to interpret `$` followed by other symbols?  There's Groovy, there's `awk` or `sed`, and the shell only keeps its hands off because the code uses single quotes instead of double quotes?  If the use of `$` (more than `$0` as in the title) is the problem, then escaping it is necessary.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I get the impression the problem is the use of `$` inside double quotes, so concatenation doesn't help much — and the expression you suggest doesn't add `ABC` to lines 2..EOF (though that's fixable).

Comment: Agreed, to avoid `$0` completely, you can use `sub`, e.g. `awk 'NR == 1 && sub (/.*/, "& name")'` which by default will be matched against the entire record. (there is a `' '` (space) between `"& name"` even though that is where the line broke in this comment)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Your regex has a `$` in it :D — they're ubiquitous, aren't they?  You could omit both the caret and the dollar and rely on greedy being greedy, though.  This is nitpicking.  I'm not sure how the script is being embedded in the context where Groovy evaluates it as being inside double quotes and not inside single quotes.  Superficially, the use of `$zero` instead of `$0` answers the headline question — but it isn't clear that the headline question is the one that needs answering.

Comment: `;p` I cleaned it up by removing the anchors. I saw that after I hit "Add Comment" and then edited. (kinda like writing `1 + 1 = 3`) It would help if the OP actually included the command that was throwing the error. I have no clue what Groovy is, so aside from the `awk` part the question, it is a bit abstract.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin — I didn't notice that you'd updated your comment while I was writing my wryly amused counter-comment.  I think that my browser (current Chrome — Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) — on macOS) didn't notice your edit, but I can't now be certain.

Answer (score 2):

`$0` is a perfectly valid character sequence within a *string* in Groovy. It's just not valid in a *string literal*.

If you want to represent `$0` in a Groovy string, write it as `"\$0"`.

Or you could use a single-quoted Groovy string literal, which doesn't support interpolation. For example, `'$0'` and `"\$0"` have the same value. (This could be a problem if you need single quotes in the string.)

(No, as far as I know there's no other way to refer to `$0` in awk.)

**UPDATE**:

Now that you've shown (a fragment of) your Groovy code, I believe you can fix it by changing both occurrences of `"""` to `'''`.

Comment: It looks like I'm getting the same error with `"\'$0"`

Comment: I think there's been some misunderstanding; I was copying what you have above

Comment: Superficially, the `awk` command is enclosed in single quotes so why is Groovy doing interpolation inside the single quotes?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm trying to put the awk command inside three double quote strings, e.g. `""" here """`

Comment: @EB2127 — that (`""" … """`) makes some sort of sense.  I think simply adding the backslash before the `$` is the simplest fix; Groovy will replace the `\$` with `$` and then everybody will be happy.

Comment: @EB2127's comments about `"\'$0"` were based on a typo in the original version of my answer, which I then corrected.